# Is return code of ArangoDB HTTP API is always the same as HTTP status code?

Tags: arangodb

Some APIs has return code in their response body and some APIs don't.

For example, the API for creating a collection has return code in its response.
https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/develop/http/collections/#create-a-collection

The API for reading a document does not have a return code in its response.
https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/develop/http/documents/#get-a-document

Currently, I'm implementing a low-level client for ArangoDB >= 3.0.
https://github.com/hnakamur/arangogo

If the return code is always the same as the response status code,
I'll use the response status code and ignore the return code in responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [RestBaseHandler.cpp](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/blob/002a1e55cb1c7f0fd47df0712c0962102b8242d6/arangod/RestHandler/RestBaseHandler.cpp#L88), it seems that the response code in the HTTP header and the `error` code returned in the body are identical.

`errorNum` uses error codes which are **sometimes** the same as HTTP error codes (with the same meaning), but usually a custom [ArangoDB error number](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/develop/error-codes-and-meanings/) will be returned.

Comment: Thanks!
I confirmed `code` in responses body are identical to the response status code.